# Plotting new documents to scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, pca

I am looking to gain some insight into my data. I am converting them into VSM using sklearn PCA and plotting them to a matplotlib graph. THis involves

1. Casting the documents to a number matrix using pipeline

   ```
   test = pipeline.fit_transform(docs).todense()
   ```
2. Fitting it to my model

   ```
   pca = PCA().fit(test)
   ```
3. Then I am converting it using transform

   ```
       data = pca.transform(test)
   ```
4. Finally I am plotting the results using Matplotlib

   ```
      plt.scatter(data[:,0], data[:,1], c = categories)
   ```

My question is this: How do I take new sentences and determine where they would lie in relation to the other documents plotted. Using an X to mark their relative positions ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Also cast the new documents to a numeric array

   ```
   new = pipeline.transform(new_docs).todense()
   ```

   Note that this uses the `pipeline` with the previously fitted parameters, hence it's `pipeline.transform`, not `pipeline.fit_transform`.
2. Transform the new data using the previously fitted `pca`.

   ```
   new_data = pca.transform(new)
   ```

   This will transform the new data to the same PC-space as the original data.
3. Add the new data to the plot using a second `scatter`.

   ```
   plt.scatter(data[:,0], data[:,1], c = categories)
   plt.scatter(new_data[:,0], new_data[:,1], marker = 'x')
   plt.show()
   ```